# Nhibernate and WCF IList<> Conflict

Tags: wcf, fluent-nhibernate

i'll use some sample code to demonstrate my problem...

this is an entity

```
public class Channel : EntityBase
{

    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<LocalChannel> LocalChannels { get; set; }
}
```

local channel has a string property.

this 2 classes mapped fluently and works fine with the has many relation.

the problem is in the wcf service.

when i'm selecting a channel or all channels.

the localChannels list is fixed size. (the type of ILIst that returns is typed array)

i want i to be a List.

Nhibernate wont let me to write this:

```
public virtual List<LocalChannel> LocalChannels { get; set; }
```

becuase it cant cast his collections to List

and my proxy is written in code and not generated with svcutil so i cant change the collection type.

any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my answer to [Manually change the ClientBase collection type from Array[] to List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537958/manually-change-the-clientbase-collection-type-from-array-to-list)

Does the NHibernate projection and DataContract projection have to be the same? I don't know much about NHibernate, but can you do something like this?

```
public class Channel : EntityBase{

  //For WCF
  [DataMember(Name="LocalChannel")]
  private List<LocalChannel> LocalChannelsPrivate {
     get {return new List<LocalChannel>(LocalChannels);}
    set {LocalChannels=value;}
  }

  //For NHibernate
  public virtual IList<LocalChannel> LocalChannels {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: 10x nice idea..
i think i just use the svc util and avoid patch.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative to the accepted answer if you don't want to use multiple properties. It takes advantage of how WCF deserializes properties. Using the technique described in [this](http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/blog/201005/wcf-and-ilistt) post, you could code the class as follows:

```
        public class Channel : EntityBase{

            //Initialize backing var to an empty list or null as desired.
            private IList<LocalChannel> _localChannels = new List<LocalChannel>();

            //For WCF & NHibernate:
            [DataMember]
            public virtual IList<LocalChannel> LocalChannels
            {
                get {return _localChannels;}
                set {_localChannels = new List<LocalChannel>(value);}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Sixto Saez answer. Just with one note: with this, IList will always be of type List. On other side, NHibernate proxy can have his own collection which inherits IList<...>. So, we can allow NHibernate to insert his collection, except in case when collection is of type array. Like this:

```
    private IList<LocalChannel> _localChannels ;
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<LocalChannel> LocalChannels {
        get
        {
            return _localChannels ?? (_localChannels = new List<LocalChannel>());
        }
        set
        {
            _localChannels = value.GetType() == typeof(LocalChannel[])
                                ? new List<LocalChannel>(value)
                                : value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private IList<LocalChannel>channels;

public List<LocalChannel>Channels{ get { return this.channels as List<LocalChannel>; } set{ this.channels = value;}
```

NHibernate will be able to use IList but your public interface can use List

Comment: this can't be done cause nhibernate implement IList<> but not inherit List, the Channels is actually a Persistance bag or some other collection implementation of nhibernate.
so the cast is impossible, thats why i cant use List<>