# Getting List on WCF ChannelFactory Generated Client Proxy when IList is used in the Entity

Tags: wcf

There is a famous issue with WCF which is serializing IList as array (instead of list) to the client. There are also known solutions which can be applied when the client is using svcutil or the Visual Studio IDE for creating the service reference for the client.
However, we are using ChannelFactory to generate a service proxy to the client at run time. In other words, we don't use svcutil nor the IDE to create a reference to the service.
Is there an appropriate solution to this problem with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to do something similar to what I describe [in my answer to a question on IList with NHibernate & WCF.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538811/nhibernate-and-wcf-ilist-conflict/3132519#3132519) Since you are sharing the contract assembly between the service and the client, the List deserialization code will also be shared. I have used this technique with a ChannelFactory approach successfully, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your service interface, is your return type list? Is just did a short test,

Server:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri("http://localhost:1024/TestService"));
        host.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public List<string> GetStrings(string test)
    {
        return new List<string>() {test};
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> GetStrings(string test);
}
```

Client

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<ITestService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(new BasicHttpBinding());
        ITestService proxy = factory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:1024/TestService")));
        var list = proxy.GetStrings("Test");
    }
```

And list will be of type List. Did you handle anything different in your implementation?

Comment: I am using a POCO entity which has an automatic property of type IList<XXX>

Comment: So your ServiceInterface is using your POCO Entity and you´re using the same interface to instantiate your client proxy via the ChannelFactory?

Comment: Yes. And naturally the entity class must be a code which is shared between client and server, so it's defined in an assembly referenced by both

Comment: OK, than I dont understand how you can encounter an array in your client code if the interface defines an IList. Can you extent your question with code samples?