# System.Activities.Statements.AddToCollection Giving Fixed Size Error

Tags: collections, workflow-foundation-4

In my workflow I call a service which returns me a List. The problem is that in my workflow i use a AddToCollection Activitie to add a new string to the collection, but i get an error right when i get to the activity.

Debugging and checking i got to theworkflow logs and now I see that the error is that "Collection was of a fixed size." Here's the complete log:

> System.SZArrayHelper.Add[T](T value)
>   System.Activities.Statements.AddToCollection`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

What i don't get is why (and how this happened)? Is this a bug? I specifically return a List... why does it says it's fixed sized?!?

EDIT 1: There's something really weird... since my original workflow was quite big I created a new, smaller one, just to reproduce this error... and I can't!

Comment: Your service is probably returning an array, which indeed is a IList but items cannot be added to it.

Comment: @Jota That was correct! in the service configuration i was setting colletion to System.Array! But the problem remains...

Comment: Can you show the service code where the list is handled and returned?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that WCF is serializing your list to array before sending it over the wire. Don't know if it is possible to avoid.

Anyway, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536760/wcf-generic-list-serialized-to-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537958/manually-change-the-clientbase-collection-type-from-array-to-list)

You can also create a new Variable on your workflow and assign a List to it when you receive it from the service:

```cs
listWFVariable = new List<string>(arrayReceivedFromWebService);
```

Now you can make Add operations to it.